# ERROR TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function at BookService.push

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-services

So here is my books.service.ts code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

//import {catch} from 'rxjs/operator';

//import { toPromise } from 'rxjs/operator';

import { Book } from './book';

//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import 'rxjs/add/operators/catch';

import 'rxjs/operators/toPromise';



@Injectable()
export class BookService 
{
    url = "http://localhost:4200/assets/data/books.json";

    constructor(private http:Http) { }

    getBooksWithObservable(): Observable<Book[]> 
    {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
    }
    getBooksWithPromise(): Promise<Book[]> 
    {
        return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
    }
    private extractData(res: Response) 
    {
        let body = res.json();
        return body;
    }
    private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) 
    {
        console.error(error.message || error);
        return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
    }
    private handleErrorPromise (error: Response | any) 
    {
        console.error(error.message || error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }   
}
```

Running the command : ng serve --open , it gives the following Error :

```
ERROR in src/app/book.service.ts(24,12): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.
```

Also it gives me other error and that is in observable.component.ts. Here is the code of observable.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { BookService } from './book.service';
import { Book } from './book';

@Component({

   selector: 'app-observable',

   templateUrl: './observable.component.html'

})

export class ObservableComponent implements OnInit {

   observableBooks: Observable<Book[]>;

   books: Book[];

   errorMessage: String;

   constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {

        this.observableBooks = this.bookService.getBooksWithObservable();               

        console.log('observable');

        alert('observable');


        console.log(this.observableBooks);

        this.observableBooks.subscribe(

            books => this.books = books,

            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
   }    
}
```

I am getting the following error in this file :

`src/app/observable.component.ts(23,4): error TS2345: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(error: any) => void'`.

Can anybody solve this please, Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The map function that you import from rxJs is a pipable operator.

You should use it like this: `this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(this.extractData))`.
And you should use it like that rather than importing from `rxjs/add/operator/map` as suggested below, because it is the recommended way of using operators with RxJs >= v5.X

Also, you should use `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http` instead of `Http`.

Comment: What version of angular are you using? 
You should use the HttpClient. Http is deprecated and will (already has?) dissapear.

Comment: I m using Angular 2 as i just began with angular. New to it and directly going for updated methods won't let me understand the previous concepts like "how to use htttp"

Comment: I fail to understand your reasoning. Learning an obsolete version of the framework won't do you any good. But anyways, it's a free world ;-).
As for your problem, you'll have to play with your imports as the other responses suggest.

Comment: Wait, forget what I just said. I just saw your comment below and you are actually using angular v6.x and rxjs v6.x. So you should use them the way I told you. That's the proper way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` instead of `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Already added but it shows the following error : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map' in 'D:\Projects\wamp\www\ang\angular-books-demo\src\app'

Comment: have you installed rxjs dependancies?

Comment: Yes my friend ! its there

Answer (score 0):

**For first solution:** 
*Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.*

You need to import

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Second solution:

try removing `void` from `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {

        this.observableBooks = this.bookService.getBooksWithObservable();               

        console.log('observable');

        alert('observable');


        console.log(this.observableBooks);

        this.observableBooks.subscribe(

            books: any  => this.books = books,

            error: any =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
   }
```

Comment: do you have `rxjs` installed in `package.json`

Comment: While importing 'rxjs/add/operator/map', i m getting the error : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map' in 'D:\Projects\wamp\www\ang\angular-books-demo\src\app'    And there is nothing happening on removing void :-(

Comment: Yes, rxjs is installed : have a look to my dependencies in package.json. "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },

Comment: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`
next
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: Not happening. It says : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in 'D:\Projects\wamp\www\ang\angular-books-demo\src\app'

Comment: what happens if you take `observable` instead of `Observable`

Comment: and also remove `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Ya now that observable wala error has gone. Now its : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map' in 'D:\Projects\wamp\www\ang\angular-books-demo\src\app'

Comment: I think you should downgrade your rxjs version.

Comment: also, once remove map thing and add `import 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: Adding import 'rxjs/Rx' says Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Rx' in 'D:\Projects\wamp\www\ang\angular-books-demo\src\app'

Comment: ok wait, it should search in `node_modules` but instead it is going for `D:\Projects\wamp\www\ang\angular-books-demo\src\app`, are u using angular cli?

Comment: @JitendraAhuja, which versionof angular and are u using `angular-cli`

Comment: M using Angular 2 and yes its angular-cli

Comment: @JitendraAhuja, please change `"rxjs": "6.0.0-beta.1"` and add
`"rxjs-compat": "6.0.0-beta.1",` if it not works, try with `"rxjs": "6.1.0",` and 
`"rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",`

Comment: now My code in book.service.ts like this : getBooksWithObservable(): Observable<Book[]> 
    {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
   .pipe(map(this.extractData))
                .catchError(this.handleErrorObservable);
    } and imported lines are : import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Book } from './book';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'; and now the error is error TS2339: Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Comment: remove that `catchError` for now and check whats cmng